# explicit constructor still doing conversions

Tags: c++

I have a (very) simple templated type that lets me return a "IsValid" flag when returning from functions. It goes as follows:

```
template <typename T>
struct Validated
{
private:
    T m_value;
    bool m_isValid;

public:
    Validated() : m_value(), m_isValid(false) {}
    explicit Validated(T const& value) : m_value(value), m_isValid(true) {}
    explicit Validated(bool isValid, T const& value) : m_value(value), m_isValid(isValid) {}
    explicit Validated(bool isValid, T&& value) : m_value(value), m_isValid(isValid) {}    

    bool IsValid() const { return m_isValid; }
    T const& Value() const { return m_value; }
};
```

Maybe there's something I don't understand with the `explicit` specifier, but I was wondering why the following works just fine, and how could I avoid the conversion from bool to double?

```
void someFunc()
    {
    Validated<double> foo(1.0); // this makes perfect sense
    Validated<double> bar(true); // works... (sets m_value to 1.0)
    }
```

Been looking at similar questions/answers but couldn't find any that is satisfactory. I am aware `std::optional` exists but we're not into c++17 yet. Tried this on VS2012/v110.

Update: as suggested, deleting the constructor for bool does the job (starting from c++14). It does not work for c++11 (VS2012/toolset v110).

Comment: Those are both explicit constructor calls.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I thought explicit was about disallowing any kind of conversion, but in this case a bool is still converted to a double in a way or another?

Comment: @AlexG `explicit` disallows implicit conversion from constructor arguments (e.g. `T` in your case) to the constructed type (`Validated<T>` in your case). It does not disallow implicit conversion to the arguments of the explicit constructor.

Comment: No, it's about not allowing implicit constructor calls.

Comment: I'm guessing @AlexG wants to disable everything except double? It isn't just bool that is the issue?

Comment: @GemTaylor -- anything that's convertible to `double` will work as an argument in the code in the question.

Comment: @PeteBecker - indeed, but the attempted solutions seem to be a bit focused on bool as the only issue...

Comment: @PeteBecker GemTaylor It is meant to support basic types as well as more complex types. My concern is mainly with undesired conversions from 'bool' because the other constructors use it to set m_isValid. I can live with int/uint mismatch, though it'd be good to catch them too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply delete the constructor taking a single `bool`:

```
Validated(bool value) = delete;
```

Note: You may need some extra precautions if you want `Validated<bool>` to be a valid type.

---

You can also prevent construction from any type other than `T` (stronger than the previous one):

```
template <class U>
Validated(U) = delete;
```

This will work even with `Validated<bool>` because construction from `T` will match your `Validated(T const&)` overload while construction from any type other than `T` will match the deleted template.

This method would prevent (even explicit) construction of `Validated<double>` from `1`, `1f`, etc., so you may not want to use it.

---

`explicit` does not make your code ill-formed, it prevents implicit construction of a `Validated<T>` from a `T`, e.g.:

```
void f(Validated<double>);

f(1.0); // ill-formed because the conversion would be implicit
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems whenever I come in here (stackoverflow) it reminds me how little I know about programming...
Deleting the constructor that takes bool does the job. (Who would want a flag on top of another flag anyway?) Doesn't seem to work with c++11 (VS2012), but works for VS2015 or more recent which is fine for me. Second approach is a bit too restrictive.

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the Validated(bool) constructor in all cases apart from when T=bool
Something like...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;
template <typename T>
struct Validated
{
private:
    T m_value;
    bool m_isValid;

public:
    Validated() : m_value(), m_isValid(false) {}


    explicit Validated(T const& value) : m_value(value), m_isValid(true) {}

    template <typename Y=T,typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<Y,bool>::value,int>::type =0>
    explicit Validated(bool const& value) = delete;

    explicit Validated(bool isValid, T const& value) : m_value(value), m_isValid(isValid) {}
    explicit Validated(bool isValid, T&& value) : m_value(value), m_isValid(isValid) {}    

    bool IsValid() const { return m_isValid; }
    T const& Value() const { return m_value; }
};

int main() {
    Validated<bool> v(true);
    //Validated<int> v2(true); //fails
    Validated<int> v2(2);
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/09eRis)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that argument passed to the constructor can be implicitly converted to constructor argument type. To prevent this you can convert constructor into a template and check that type of argument exactly matches template parameter:

```
template<typename TT> explicit
Validated(TT const& value) : m_value{value}, m_isValid{true}
{
   static_assert
   (
       ::std::is_same_v<TT, T>
   ,   "constructor argument type should match template parameter"
   );
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RFT1uNv87xUHOgca)